Entity Framework Core not catching exception from stored procedure when thrown from a SQL catch block
We hit this issue in one of our applications so I wrote a simple test console app to reproduce it. I have Entity Framework Core calling a SQL Server stored procedure, and when that stored procedure throws an error from the catch block, Entity Framework Core does not catch that error. It simply populates the result list with zero items but no error.
I discovered that if I remove the try/catch from the stored procedure and throw the same error, then EF Core does in fact catch it. However I need the try/catch as there's other stuff I need to do there. I've seem some related posts where people aren't actually populating the result set (not calling .ToList() or the like) and people are saying that running async was the issue but I called it synchronously and that didn't change the outcome.
My simple test console app:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SQLExceptionTest.Models;

var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TESTNU40Context>();

builder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=MyServer; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Integrated Security=True; TrustServerCertificate=True");

var context = new TESTNU40Context(builder.Options);

try
{
    var r = context.SQLExceptionTestResults.FromSqlInterpolated($"SqlExceptionTest").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"Result count: { r.Count}");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();

My stored procedure:
create procedure SqlExceptionTest
as
    set nocount on;

    begin try
        select 1/0 as test;
    end try
    begin catch
        -- EF Core doesn't catch this error
        throw 51000, 'throw in catch', 1
    end catch

If I execute the stored procedure from a query window I get the error I expect:

Msg 51000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sqlexceptiontest, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 2]
throw in catch

So why is Entity Framework Core not catching the error?
Thanks in advance for your help.

What happens if you just re-throw the exception in the Sproc with THROW;?   The only other thing is the missing semicolon on your throw.

Does it change if you use FromSqlInterpolated($"EXECUTE SqlExceptionTest") like the SQL Queries documentation examples use?

@StevePy I tried rethrowing the exception after the original throw and I also added semicolons after both throws and still no luck.

@AlwaysLearning I changed it to EXECUTE SqlExceptionTest but no luck there either. I did discover that if I change the stored procedure from a select to a set (declare @r float = 1/0;) then EF does in fact catch the exception. Why on earth would that make a difference???

If you have a select in the stored procedure, EF will first check the shape of the result set without actually executing the code. You should get an exception that the select doesn't contain all required columns.

@GertArnold Not sure I follow. If the stored procedure has a select I get no exception at all.

OK, then in reality you apparently have select that contains all required columns for the entities in "SQLExceptionTestResults". The point is that a SELECT triggers pre-inspection of the (first) result set produced by the stored procedure w/o executing the code. However, if it executes because the pre-inspection was OK then I'd expect the query to throw if it does return results (not if there are no results).

@GertArnold Okay so my stored proc WOULD return a correctly structured result if no exception were thrown, but an exception is in fact thrown from my catch block in the stored procedure so the question remains, how do I get EF/C# to recognize that an exception was thrown from the stored procedure? And as I mentioned, if I remove the try/catch from the stored procedure and let it throw on its own, then EF/C# does catch the exception so I'd like to understand what the difference is there. Or stated differently, how do I throw an exception from my stored proc catch block so EF/C# will catch it?
